# Wordpress site running on Google computer engine inaccessible after instance stop & start

Tags: wordpress, apache2, google-compute-engine

The instance has the apache2 service running, however it is not allowing HTTP requests. What could possibly have changed on restart? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned "restart" and "google-compute-engine" tag in your question, it is possible that if IP assigned to the instance was an [ephemeral external IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#ephemeraladdress)  which means if you stop and start the VM instance or delete the instance then external ephemeral external IP assigned to that instance will be released and there is no guarantee that you will retain the same IP address back. So, IP must have changed for the webserver when you restarted the VM instance.

You will need to update the required 'A' DNS record to point to the new IP address assigned to the VM instance, if that is the case.

If planning on hosting websites, I would recommend using static external IP addresses. [Static external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) can be reserved and assign to the VM instances. This will make sure external IP address assigned to the VM instance will be persistent throughout the lifecycle of the instance.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a million things. You haven't given any information. What exactly happens when you http into it. Can you SSH? FTP? I've had a corrupted DB once when I hard re-booted an Ubuntu box.

Comment: The external IP is pingable, SSH is possible. This is something to do with the external ephimeral IP although I have no idea how to go about fixing it.